# Managing Azure Backups

Tags: azure, system-center

I'm using the Azure Backup Agent on a couple of Azure VMs to backup files to an Azure Backup Vault.  I don't see a way to monitor or receive notifications on the status of the backups through the agent.  From my searching it appears that System Center DPM is the answer.  I'm a developer, not a systems engineer (I was in the NT 4.0 days), so I'm not familiar with DPM and I'm not even sure it is the right answer.

So, my question is this...what are my options for monitoring backups created using Azure Backup Agent on dozens of Azure VMs and local servers?  Will System Center with DPM work where I have a mix of servers in Azure and in other data centers as well?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found a TechNet blog post from May 2014 that describes "complete configuration steps of using Azure backup from a System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM) perspective". So hopefully, the blog post is somewhat useful to you or someone else who has stumbled upon this unanswered question, posted Sep 2014.

- **Using and Monitoring Azure Backup for Windows Server**
  : http://blogs.technet.com/b/systemcenter/archive/2014/05/08/using-and-monitoring-azure-backup-for-windows-server.aspx